# discord interaction.deferUpdate() is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js, roles

I'm creating a message with buttons as reaction roles but do the reaction role handling in another file so it stays loaded after a reset but it either says "interaction.deferUpdate() is not a function, or in discord it says "this interaction failed" but it gave/removed the role

my code for creating the message:

```
const { ApplicationCommandType, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'role',
    description: "reactionroles",
    cooldown: 3000,
    userPerms: ['Administrator'],
    botPerms: ['Administrator'],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        const getButtons = (toggle = false, choice) => {
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setLabel('member')
                        .setCustomId('member')
                        .setStyle(toggle == true && choice == 'blue' ? 'Secondary' : 'Primary')
                        .setDisabled(toggle),
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setLabel('member2')
                        .setCustomId('member2')
                        .setStyle(toggle == true && choice == 'blue' ? 'Secondary' : 'Primary')
                        .setDisabled(toggle),
            );

            return row;
        }

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Wähle eine rolle')
        .setDescription('Wähle die rolle, die du gern haben möchtest')
        .setColor('Aqua')

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [getButtons()] })
        .then((m) => {
            const collector = m.createMessageComponentCollector();
            collector.on('collect', async (i) => {
                if (!i.isButton()) return;
                await i.deferUpdate();
                
                
            });

        });
    }
};
```

code for the reaction role:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require('chalk')
var AsciiTable = require('ascii-table')
var table = new AsciiTable()
const discord = require("discord.js");
table.setHeading('Events', 'Stats').setBorder('|', '=', "0", "0")

module.exports = (client) => {
    

    client.ws.on("INTERACTION_CREATE", async (i) => {
        
        let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('934096845762879508');
        let member = await guild.members.fetch(i.member.user.id)
        let role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === i.data.custom_id);
        if (!member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
            member.roles.add(role);
        } else {
            member.roles.remove(role);
        }
        return i.deferUpdate()
    })
};
```

Comment: What version of DiscordJS are you using?

Comment: @Elitezen version 14.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `client.ws` events give raw data (not discord.js objects), so the `.deferUpdate()` method doesn't exist there. You should be using `client.on("interactionCreate")`

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", async (i) => {
  // ...
  return i.deferUpdate()
})
```